# How do I make the QR code open Expo DevClient when the Preview app is also installed on iOS?

Tags: ios, expo, expo-dev-client

I want to install both a preview and devclient on my iPhone. I presume you need to set two different app IDs (slugs) so they don’t conflict. However, the QR code will only open for the preview app rather than the devclient.

I made it both have the same `scheme` as well.

Is there anything else I may be missing?

On Android, I recall seeing a pop up that asks which app to use but I don't recall the same capability in iOS.